# Escaping filename spaces with singularity %files directive

Tags: singularity-container

I have a file with spaces in its name that I want to copy to my container:

```
%files
   /tmp/some file with spaces /usr/local/bin
```

I have tried using 1 or 2 backslashes paired with single or double quotes, but the full filename is not recognized.  While I can change the filename, I was curious if there is a way to correctly escape the filename?

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it does not appear they can be escaped. (There's a similar problem with trying to mount file names with `:`.) You might try raising an issue in [the github repo](https://github.com/hpcng/singularity).